# how to handle "move target out of bounds: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document."

Tags: javascript, selenium, jenkins, local-storage

so I get this error when trying to set the local storage with

```
browser.execute(`Object.assign(localStorage, '{here is my JSON with all the properties}))
```

this only happens when the job that is running this script runs on Jenkins. also, I haven't been able to get this error on my local machine

Move target out of bounds: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

> Error: Remote end send an unknown status code.
>   at execute("Object.assign(localStorage, {here is my JSON}))

Comment: Why not use vanilla JS methods? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: if you're trying to add a string like that, I'm not sure it will work

Comment: @hueyfreeman vanilla JS didn't work either, same security check it's thrown, i already tried setting lot of capabilities on the browser but same error